# AJAX not posting JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to post form data to another page using `AJAX` and `JSON`. Here is my AJAX code.

```
var myData = '{ "number1": ' + $("#text1").val() + ', "number2": ' + $("#text2").val() + ' }';

$.ajax({
    url: $("form").attr("action"),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response){
        var p = $("p");
        p.append(response);
        //console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(request,error,msg){
        $("p").html(error+": "+msg);
    },
    data: myData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
});
```

I am printing `$_POST` array using `print_r` function on the target page to see if any parameter has been received. But I find it empty. Getting `parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` in response.

Comment: If you add `console.log(myData);`, what exactly is the format of the JSON you're sending? Also note that it would be better practice (and possibly solve your problem) if you provide an object directly to the `data` parameter of `$.ajax`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `console.log(myData);` prints  `{ "number1": 4534534, "number2": 3543534 }` to the console.

Comment: What is the value of the `response`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have `if($_POST)
 print_r($_POST);
else 
 echo "No Data Posted!";`
this code in target php file. Getting response `No Data Posted!`

Comment: That's your problem, you're returning a string, not JSON.

Comment: Sorry @RoryMcCrossan what do i do now?

Comment: You need to return JSON. I'm not a PHP developer so I can't give you exact details of how to do that, but have a google for `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

change `var myData = '{ "number1": ' + $("#text1").val() + ', "number2": ' + $("#text2").val() + ' }';`

to

```
var myData = {  number1: $("#text1").val(),  number2: $("#text2").val() };
```

remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` and `dataType: 'json',` you are returning a string not json

your ajax should look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $("form").attr("action"),
    type: 'POST',
    data:  {  number1: $("#text1").val(),  number2: $("#text2").val() },
     success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },

});
```

your php like:

```
if($_POST) echo json_encode($_POST); else echo "No Data Posted!";
```

Comment: `console.log(myData);` printing ` Object { number1="4534534",  number2="3543534"}` to console and getting same response: `parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: @A.B. did you remove the dataType?

Comment: try removing `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`

Comment: use  `:` instead of `=`

Comment: I have removed `application/json; charset=utf-8` and `dataType` too. Getting `No data posted!` but this time with no error.

Comment: is there any data in your  `#text1`, `#text2` fields ?

Comment: this should return the print_r result,can you post your php code?

Answer (score 0):

use this

var centercode = $('#WONum').val();
                      var centerName = $('#WONum2').val();

```
                   //Now you have the value of the textbox, you can do something with it, maybe an AJAX call to your server!
                  var centerObj = {};
                  centerObj["centercode"]= $('#WONum').val();
                  centerObj["centerName"]= $('#WONum2').val();

                             var jsonData = ko.toJSON(centerObj);
                             console.log(jsonData); 


                                $.ajax({
                                    url: web_service_url + "centermaster/createCenterMaster", ///"+branchcode+"/"+branchname,
                                    data: jsonData,
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                    dataType: "jsonp",
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your `myData` with the given`myData` in code below..

```
<script>
var myData = JSON.stringify({ "number1":  $("#text1").val() , "number2": $("#text2").val() });

$.ajax({
    url: $("form").attr("action"),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response){
        var p = $("p");
        p.append(response);
        //console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(request,error,msg){
        $("p").html(error+": "+msg);
    },
    data:{myData},
    dataType: 'json'
});
</script>
```

And use `echo json_encode($_POST);` in your target file...

Comment: @A.B. try this code, this is working for me... remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` this line and replace `myData`

Comment: This posts data as object not JSON. I want the data to be posted as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myData = { number1: $("#text1").val(), number2: $("#text2").val() };

$.ajax({
    url: $("form").attr("action"),
    method: 'POST',        
    data: JSON.stringify(myData),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(response){
        var p = $("p");
        p.append(response);
        //console.log(response);
        },
    error: function(request,error,msg){
    $("p").html(error+": "+msg);
    },
});
```

Use this code.
Notice the variable myData and JSON.stringify

Comment: Getting blank array in response. `echo json_encode($_POST);` is my target code.

Comment: what is you PHP method parameter ?